# Can I use 3d model in Kudan CMS?

Tags: json, 3d-modelling, kudan

I am testing the Kudan CMS sample app. Can I use a 3d model as an augmentation? The documentation only shows text and video.

Answer (score 1):

Although the sample app is setup to demonstrate the use of videos as augmentation, you are free to modify the sample code and load up any other supported asset as an augmentation.

For 3D models you'll just need to ensure that you pass across the model file and the textures required for it. That should be a fairly trivial modification to the existing sample code.